# error connecting database to java program in netbeans

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I'm trying to connect my Java program to my database in NetBeans.
I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Help {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Date date=new Date();
        String w=String.valueOf(date);
        System.out.println(w);
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:date","user","123");
            Statement s=con.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO date(Date) VALUE ('"+w+"')");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Help.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the details of the issue you are facing!!

Comment: More details .eg. exception stacktrace is needed but check if you have required jars in classpath

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 0):

The query must be :

```
"INSERT INTO date(Date) VALUES ('"+w+"')"
```

It's VALUES, not VALUE.